# font use in app called eguru

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I found a app called enguru.I really love how it is written can any one help me to find this font?

Comment: looks like a custom font design. Have you tried any of the font identification sites? check this http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366

Comment: i did it but couldn't find in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is [Aldo Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sacha-rein/aldo-pro/) from myfonts.com. The logo uses 2 different font weights which may be "Medium" and "Black".

[image: Enguru font]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the contribution! AndrewH found the correct font based on this like you mentioned. Welcome to GraphicDesign and let us know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 (maybe 3) fonts used in this logo

The "e" I belive is [Fono Medium](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/garagefonts/fono/) (The height of the e in the logo could have been shortened).

[image: Fono Medium font]

---

The "g" is most likely customized from the letter "e".

---

The "n" and "u & r" are possibly from the same font family just using different weights.

Here are some close fonts

[Laszlo Broad](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/justmytype/laszlo/)

[image: Laszalo font example]

[Pasadena Serial Medium](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/pasadena-serial/)

[image: Pasadena font example]

Comment: @Sumann I wrote about that above. I believe the letter "g" is modified from the letter "e" and NOT an actual character from a font. It probably uses a lighter font weight than the "e".